# How to keep chicken moist from previous night?

Tags: food, snack-food

When there are leftovers, they are placed in the fridge or kept in the microwave; but they lose their moisture? In the morning, be it chicken, take away chicken or rice!

How can one keep the food from the previous night moist and edible the next day(s)?

Comment: You know that there’s Cooking SE (Seasoned Advice)?

Comment: Put it in a freezer bag, and expel all the air before closing it.

Comment: For any water-containing substance stored in a closed container, there will be a certain _equilibrium_ partial pressure of water vapor above it. How much this partial pressure is depends, e.g., on the total pressure in this container, and the temperature (one approximation is [Raoult's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raoult%27s_law)).  In a fridge, however, once the air touches the cooler surfaces, this water vapor condenses into liquid water and is funneled out of the fridge.  Because this removes water vapor of the atmosphere in the fridge, your food again "transpires" (and looses) water.

Comment: @WeatherVanev that's totally worthy as answer, a simple and effective "hack". :)

Comment: Adding a bit of water before reheating also works, but as with wrapping the food in plastic, that's a bit too obvious to count as a lifehack.

Answer (score 2):

1. Steam would be a good option, it would heat the chicken in a moist environment to prevent it dry.
2. Air circulation in the fridge will take away the water from the chicken, and the microwave will turn water in the chicken into water vapour and make the chicken dry-er. spray water on top of the chicken before microwaving, and place a small cup with water, in the bowl and add a lid will slow down the water molecule going away.
3. Use vacuum seal containers (you will need a sealer vacuum as well.)

Comment: Your solution works fine. I have heard about some 'freezer safe containers', would also do good in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

**How to keep chicken moist from previous night?**

Keep the previous meal in an air tight container inside the fridge, until it is taken out for use.

Once taken out, use the microwave to thaw or unfrozen ingredients for your meal! If necessary, please add little water to the substance before being microwaved!

By the way: [***bon appétit***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bon%20app%C3%A9tit)